# Retrieving cookies in Python using urllib2

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I am trying to retrieve the cookie from a page that is running on localhost from my own python script, but I am having trouble understanding the urllib2 documentation.  I tried looking around for some examples of retrieving cookies and couldn't really find an answer.  Would it be something along the lines of:

```
url = "http://localhost:8080"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
sock=urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

after this I don't know how I would fetch the cookies, and I don't even fully understand what this code does.

Also, is there a way to use urllib2 to send a cookie back?

Thanks!

Comment: I recomend `requests` instead of `urllib2` and `requests.Session` which care of cookies and you have to do nothing.